# Difference between connection string and service name in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle

Is there is any difference between service name and connection string in oracle.

As per i understood service name is host string in oracle?

For eg if connection string is user/user123@user_string.

then is user_string is service name or interchangebly host string.

Is this correct?

Then my another question is what is need for host string in addition to user name and password?

Comment: `user_string` refers the `TNS` entry as per `tnsnames.ora`. When the actual connection details is configured in that file, we can just mention the entry to be referred. But when you want to specify your own connection, you can specify the full `URL` including hostname,port and service name. The `TNS` file would be in `$ORACLE_HOME\network\admin\tnsnames.ora`

Answer (score 1):

Service name is nothing but the database instance.

User string is the entry in your tnsnames.ora

One should have to define their database instance with the name you should be using the user string in the tnsnames.ora to successfully get connected with oracle database.

For Example : `user/passwd@database`
You should define your oracle instance in the tnsnames.ora under database
The syntax should look like

```
database=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = databaseinstance)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Actually what is mean by instance, consider We have some memory. we have created the database. consider as database1. Is database1 is one instance. Am i correct

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't like to use your tnsnames.ora file you can do also this one:

```
user/user123@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=databaseinstance)))"
```

I assume the quotes are only required if you connect string contains space characters.

Comment: Deviating from my question. Need another clarification is port number 1521 is common to all oracle installation. Even my system have the same port number

Comment: It's the default port number, but you can choose other ports for the listener if you like.

Comment: Fine.. ok then consider two instance as instance1 and instance2. I have a user called vinoth in instance1. can i able to create the same username in instance2 also... Is this possible?